# safari recorded video speed up issue in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, webrtc, getusermedia, recordrtc

I have implemented the WebRTC in my angular project to record the video. And after the save we can send it to the attachment. This is working fine in windows OS properly, but in mac safari, the video is speed up and 30-sec video becomes 3 sec only. this occurs only in safari.

Here on start the video.

```
  mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
  .then(webcamStream => {
    this.webcamStream = webcamStream;
  })
```

The MediaRecorder code:

```js
this.recorder = new MediaRecorder(this.webcamStream, {mimeType: 'video/mp4'});
this.recorder.onstart = () => 
    this.zone.run(() => {
      this.behaviorService.isRecording(true); 
    });
this.recorder.onstop = this.onRecorderStopped;
this.recorder.ondataavailable = (event) => 
    this.zone.run(() => { 
      this.data = [...this.data, event.data]; 
  }); 
this.recorder.start();
```

When video is stopped then it save in **video/webm;codecs=h264** this mimeType.
I have also tried with **video/mp4** but it also not working

Can I get any solution that works in both OS?

Comment: Your `ondataavailable()` handler should do `this.data.push(event.data)` instead of what you have.  And, how do you handle the data when you go to save it. Please [edit] your question. When you post code in a comment, it's ridiculously hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

Safari is notoriously broken with respect to `.getUserMedia()` and the MediaRecorder class.

> Can i get the any solution which works in both OS?

Not yet. Pester Apple.  In the meantime use Chrome on MacOS: it works.

There may be some tricks to recommend to make this better. But you didn't show us your `MediaRecorder` code: that's where the stream is compressed.

Comment: In MediaRecorder, i have used some below code,
this.recorder = new MediaRecorder(this.webcamStream, {mimeType: 'video/mp4'});
        this.recorder.onstart = () => this.zone.run(() => {
          this.behaviorService.isRecording(true);
        });
        this.recorder.onstop = this.onRecorderStopped;
        this.recorder.ondataavailable = (event) => this.zone.run(() => {
          this.data = [...this.data, event.data];
        });
        this.recorder.start();